# Как отключить автозамену в visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Только учусь работать с C#, Пишу код в visual studio  ввожу res, но C# заменяет это на ResolveEventArgs. Как отключить это автодополнение?

Comment: Можно жать Esc, когда появилась подсказка. Если замена уже произошла, нажать Ctrl+Z.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Space - шорткат для переключения между automatic and tab-only intellisense completion. / В меню пункт Edit > IntelliSense. Есть кнопка на тулбаре.

Comment: автокомплит не надо отключать, его надо приручать, учиться пользоваться